# Hibernate Constraint Violation Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring with Hibernate and I'm getting this exception.
Here is what I'm trying to get:
I have User and UserSettings classes, they're bounded with OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations like this:

```
public class UserImpl implements User, Serializable {

...some fields 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserSettingsImpl> settings;

}

public class UserSettingsImpl implements UserSettings, Serializable {

...some fields

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserImpl user;

}
```

Now, I want to add settings for user, that's how I'm doing it:

```
public long addSettings(final UserSettings settings) {
    userSettingsDAO.persist((UserSettingsImpl) settings);
    UserSettingsImpl settingsImpl = (UserSettingsImpl) settings;
    User user = settings.getUser();
    Set<UserSettingsImpl> settingsSet = (Set<UserSettingsImpl>) user.getSettingsSet();
    settingsSet.add(settingsImpl);
    userManager.updateUser(user); //it's just entityManager.merge(user);
    return ((UserSettingsImpl) settings).getId();
}
```

And here comes the problem:
User from UserSettings holds set with old settings and the new one (the settings, that I've just created and want to add), but old settings holds sets with user, that don't have new settings in it. That's why I'm getting the exception, I suppose, but I don't know how to fix it. (I think I'm working with Hibernate in the wrong way)

Comment: can you elaborate or reword what do you mean by the oldsetting and new setting?

Comment: @Hrishikesh Of course: these're settings I want to add (I also modified question)

Comment: Is addSettings a method in User?

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia no, I have a UserSettingsManager class, and this method belongs is in it

Comment: Are you saying that you end up with two User objects, one having a settings set of size 2, and one with a settings set of size 1?

Comment: just to remind you, if you use `merge`. the way it works is it will create a copy of the object and then persist and refresh the object and return it back. So, in essense, the `user` object which you do pass in to the `userManager` will not be updated, but you have to get the returning value for the updated `user`

Comment: @Hrishikesh thanks, you should make it an 'answer', so I could accept it :)

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to solve the issue. Added the comment as answer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get old `Usersettings` in the `user` object with the current setup.
It is because, the way the `merge` method works. 
The way it works is it will create a copy of the object and then `persist` and `refresh` the object and return it back. So, in essense, the `user` object which you do pass in to the `userManager` will not be updated, but you have to get the returning value for the updated `user`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like below, the userImpl is referenced by the relationship from UserSettingsImpl, if you persist UserSettingsImpl, the operation is applied to the UserImpl because of the cascade, and if UserImpl is new it will be persisted otherwise nothing happens.

```
public long saveSettings(final UserSettings settings) {
    userSettingsDAO.persist((UserSettingsImpl) settings);
    return ((UserSettingsImpl) settings).getId();
}
```

and manage the bidirectional relationship in the class UserImpl:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
 private Set<UserSettingsImpl> settings = new HashSet<UserSettingsImpl>();

 public void addUserSettings(UserSettings userSettings) {
    this.settings.add(userSettings);
    userSettings.setUserImpl(this);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to update User. In this case, do I need adding settings to the Set?